# Replace values with values from another field of the same data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have `data.frame` containing travel Duration time from several cities to some destinations. The structure (simplified) looks like the table below:

```
city  | dest1 | dest2 | closest
------+-------+-------+--------
cityA | NA    | NA    | cityC
cityB | NA    | NA    | cityD
cityC | 100   | 200   | cityA
cityD | 300   | 400   | cityB
```

Now I want to approximate the travel duration from `cityA` to `dest1` by the travel duration from `cityC` to `dest1` (because `cityC` is closest to `cityA`, last column), i.e. I want to replace the `NA` value in the upper left with `100`.

Is there a possibility to do this smoothly with `dplyr` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `left_join` with some selecting/renaming, a `mutate` with `coalesce` to merge the columns and a `select` to remove what you don't want from the output.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(city = c("CityA","CityB","CityC","CityD"),
              dest1 = c(NA, NA, 100, 300),
              dest2 = c(NA, NA, 200, 400),
              closest = c("CityC","CityD","CityA","CityB"))


df %>% 
  left_join(select(., city = closest, dist = dest1), by = "city") %>% 
  mutate(dest1 = coalesce(dist, dest1)) %>% 
  select(-dist)
```